# Basic Routing Example Not Working

Tags: php, routes, silex

I am working on an inherited project that uses Silex 1.3. I am trying to debug something but I cannot define any new routes when running the application.

The `Stripe` class and `connect` method is being called;

```
use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ControllerProviderInterface;

class Stripe implements ControllerProviderInterface
{
    public function connect(Application $app)
    {
        $app->get('/something', function () {
            return 'Main home page';
        });

        $app->get('/hello/{name}', function ($name) use ($app) {
            return 'Hello '.$app->escape($name);
        });

        $routes = $app['routes']->all();

        var_dump($routes);
        exit;
```

When is use something like Paw/Postman all I get is an empty array for `$routes`. If I do a `var_dump` at the top of the connect function I get something **so I know that this method is being called**.

Why are these routes not being added? What am I missing?

Comment: `var_dump($routes);` is empty because the routes aren't (yet) [flushed](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Application.php#L494). Only after you "run" the application `$app['routes']` will be populated.

Comment: If you try to add `$app->flush()` before `$routes = ...` you should able to see them.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `get()` on the `Application` instance, but instead on the controllers factory – see [documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/providers.html#id3). Plus, you then have to return the controllers.